# oracle sql Laravel migrate error

Tags: sql, oracle, laravel

i am having problem to run php artisan migrate command.
i have a laravel connecting to oracle sql.

i have clean laravel instalation,
i have installed Yajra library
oci driver installed and working

i have tested to connect to database with a php test file and was successful.

next i created migration, in my migration i added single string field

now i want to migrate the table but iam getting error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mvKB.png)

I was looking online for ORA 00903 error but none of tem applied to  my problem

Comment: I don't know oracle, but it looks like you didn't specify the name of the table you are creating? https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables003.htm#ADMIN01503

Comment: Thanks, name of the table is specified in laravel migrations file
        'Schema::create('testTable', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('name');
        });'

Comment: Look at your screenshot though -- no name is specified, so there must be something wrong with the configuration?

Comment: migrations are now working, you were correct with something being wrong with the laravel configuration, i have reinstall laravel as well. thanks for pointing to missing table name in the query.